# Selecting data from multiple Treeview components in Vuejs

Tags: vuejs2, treeview, vuetify.js, selected

I have multiple vuetify treeviews in vue and I want to retrieve the node name from each treeview according to which I select. This is sort of a merge tool with a treeview on the left and one of the right. Using selected.name as a model on the middle template to display this is only getting my right treeview selection (and it's not dependent on the first tree I click). How do you differentiate between the two trees based upon node click/select please?

Answer (score 0):

One way of dealing with this is to emit different events from each of the treeviews. You could have a prop of type string on your treeview component which you append/prepend to any events emited.

Meaning, if before the Treeview emitted the event 'hello', you can pass in the prop 'left-tree' for the left Treeview, and have your event inside of the Treeview component emit 'left-tree-hello' for example. For the right Treeview, you'd pass in 'right-tree', thus emitting 'right-tree-hello'.

Alternatively, you can just have different event listeners on your parent component, one for the left one and another for the right.